# Java how to add multiple class values to 1 list and then parse through that list with repeated prompt?

Tags: java, arrays

I currently have 5 classes that take a couple entries and store that information. These 5 classes are vanClass, truckClass and so on. In my AutoPark class, I create 2 instances of all 5 classes and have 10 variables that all contain the info I gave when I declared them. See below to understand what I'm calling:

```
sedan1 = new sedan("Ford" , "Model-1" , "white" , 2015, 20000); // initialising sedan1 using sedan constructor
sedan2 = new sedan("Toyota" , "Model-2" , "gray" , 2010, 12000); // initialising sedan2 using sedan constructor

suv1 = new SUV("Ford" , "Model-1" , "white" , 2015, 20000, true); // initialising suv1 using SUV constructor
suv2 = new SUV("Toyota" , "Model-2" , "gray" , 2010, 12000, false); // initialising suv1 using SUV constructor
truck1 = new truckClass("Ford" , "Model-1" , 2015, 20000, true, "goods"); // initialising truck using truck constructor
truck2 = new truckClass("Toyota" , "Model-2" , 2010, 12000, false, "equipment"); // initialising truck using truck constructor
```

I need to be able to search through all the string values from the 10 instances of the 5 classes. How would I add all String values from the classes to produce this:

Here's an example of what I mean:

```
Enter a string to search: FORD
There is a matching item available in our inventory
Enter a string to search: Sedan hatch back
No such item is available in our inventory.
Enter a string to search: honDA
There is a matching item available in our inventory
Enter a string to search: just a tire
No such item is available in our inventory.
Enter a string to search: quit
```

Here's the complete code to understand a little better

```
import java.util.*;

class sedan {
    String make;
    String model;
    String color;
    int year;
    double price;
    boolean fourWD;
    boolean isheavyDuty;
    String carries;

    public sedan(String initMake, String initModel, String initColor, int initYear, double initPrice) {
        make = initMake;
        model = initModel;
        color = initColor;
        year = initYear;
        price = initPrice;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        String name = "Sedan";
        String main = (color + " " + make + " " + model + " " + name + " (" + year + ") costs $" + price);
        return main;
    }
}

class SUV {

    String make;
    String model;
    String color;
    int year;
    double price;
    boolean fourWD;
    String carries;

    public SUV(String initMake, String initModel, String initColor, int initYear, double initPrice, boolean initFourWD){
        make = initMake;
        model = initModel;
        color = initColor;
        year = initYear;
        price = initPrice;
        fourWD = initFourWD;
    }

    public String toString() {
        String name = "SUV";
        String main = new String();
        if (fourWD) {
            main = ("4WD " + color + " " + make + " " + model + " " + name + " (" + year + ") costs $" + price);
        }
        else {
            main = (color + " " + make + " " + model + " " + name + " (" + year + ") costs $" + price);
        }

        return main;
    }
}

class truckClass {

    String make;
    String model;
    String color;
    int year;
    double price;
    boolean fourWD;
    boolean isheavyDuty;
    String carries;

    public truckClass(String initMake, String initModel, int initYear, double initPrice, boolean initisheavyDuty, String initCarries) {
        make = initMake;
        model = initModel;
        year = initYear;
        price = initPrice;
        isheavyDuty = initisheavyDuty;
        carries = initCarries;

    }

    public String toString() {
        String name = "Truck";
        String main;
        if (isheavyDuty) {
            main = (make + " " + model + " heavy duty " + name + " (" + year + ") carries " + carries + " costs $" + price);

        }
        else {
            main = (make + " " + model + " " + name + " (" + year + ") carries " + carries + " costs $" + price);
        }

        return main;
    }
}
class vanClass {

    String make;
    String model;
    int year;
    double price;
    boolean isCovered;
    String carries;

    public vanClass(String initMake, String initModel, int initYear, double initPrice, boolean initisCovered, String initCarries){
        make = initMake;
        model = initModel;
        year = initYear;
        price = initPrice;
        isCovered = initisCovered;
        carries = initCarries;

    }

    public String toString() {
        String name;
        String main;
        if (isCovered){
            name = "covered Van";
            main = (make + " " + model + " " + name + " (" + year + ") carries " + carries + " costs $" + price);
        }
        else {
            name = "Van";
            main = (make + " " + model + " " + name + " (" + year + ") carries " + carries + " costs $" + price);
        }
        return main;
    }
}

class tireClass {

    int wheelDiameter;
    int sectionWidth;
    double price;
    boolean isPassengerTire;

    public tireClass(int initwheelDiameter, int initsectionWidth, double initPrice, boolean initisPassengerTire) {
        wheelDiameter = initwheelDiameter;
        sectionWidth = initsectionWidth;
        price = initPrice;
        isPassengerTire = initisPassengerTire;

    }

    public String toString() {
        String name;
        String main;
        if (isPassengerTire) {
            name = "Passenger tire ";
            main = (name + "with " + wheelDiameter + " in. wheel diameter " + sectionWidth +  "mm. section width, costs $" + price);
        }
        else {
            name = "Tire ";
            main = (name + "with " + wheelDiameter + " in. wheel diameter " + sectionWidth + "mm. section width, costs $" + price);
        }
        return main;

        }

    }

class AutoPark {
    String name;
    private sedan sedan1, sedan2;
    private SUV suv1, suv2;
    private truckClass truck1, truck2;
    private vanClass van1,van2;
    private tireClass tire1, tire2;
    private String item;
    private List myList;



    public AutoPark(String initName) {
        name = initName;
        sedan1 = new sedan("Ford" , "Model-1" , "white" , 2015, 20000); // initialising sedan1 using sedan constructor
        sedan2 = new sedan("Toyota" , "Model-2" , "gray" , 2010, 12000); // initialising sedan2 using sedan constructor

        suv1 = new SUV("Ford" , "Model-1" , "white" , 2015, 20000, true); // initialising suv1 using SUV constructor
        suv2 = new SUV("Toyota" , "Model-2" , "gray" , 2010, 12000, false); // initialising suv1 using SUV constructor

        truck1 = new truckClass("Ford" , "Model-1" , 2015, 20000, true, "goods"); // initialising truck using truck constructor
        truck2 = new truckClass("Toyota" , "Model-2" , 2010, 12000, false, "equipment"); // initialising truck using truck constructor

        van1 = new vanClass("Ford" , "Model-1" , 2015, 12000, true, "goods");
        van2 = new vanClass("Toyota" , "Model-2" , 2010, 45000, false, "equipment");

        tire1 = new tireClass(12,35,400,true);
        tire2 = new tireClass(8,45,350,false);

        List<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>();
        myList.add(sedan1.make);
        myList.add(sedan1.color);
        myList.add(sedan1.model);
        System.out.println(myList);


        }
    public void displayAllItems() {
        System.out.println("The " + name + " includes:");
        System.out.println(sedan1);
        System.out.println(sedan2);
        System.out.println(suv1);
        System.out.println(suv2);
        System.out.println(truck1);
        System.out.println(truck2);
        System.out.println(van1);
        System.out.println(van2);
        System.out.println(tire1);
        System.out.println(tire2);
    }

    public void searchItems(String initItem){
        //checks toString of any product in the parks inventory

        item = initItem;

        while (true) {
            if (myList.contains(item)) {
                System.out.println("TRUE");
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("False!");
            }
            break;
        }
    }
}

class AutoParkTesterProgram {
    public void main() {
        AutoPark a1;
        a1 = new AutoPark("Carleton Auto park");
        //a1.displayAllItems();

        //then loop repeatedly promt user to enter an item to search for
        //when type quit, process stops and program end
        //otherwise, searchitems of autopark used to search and result should be printed
        /*
Enter a string to search: FORD
There is a matching item available in our inventory
Enter a string to search: Sedan hatch back
No such item is available in our inventory.
Enter a string to search: honDA
There is a matching item available in our inventory
         */

    }
}


public class auto {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        AutoPark a1;
        a1 = new AutoPark("Carleton Auto park");
        //a1.displayAllItems();
        a1.searchItems("ford");



    }
}
```

Comment: You seem to have made a good start.  What problems are you having?

Comment: Hint: use the Scanner class to get input from prompt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sort of problem is the perfect opportunity to use classes. Java is an Object-Oriented language, and you can use it to model similar behavior so you don't repeat yourself in multiple places.

The majority of your classes are cars, so what better way to represent this than to create a `Car` class? A lot of the fields are shared between the car classes, and they can all be moved into one place like so:

```
public abstract class Car {
  public String make;
  public String model;
  public String color;
  public int year;
  public double price;
  public String carries;

  public Car(String make, String model, String color, int year, double price, String carries) {
    this.make = make;
    this.model = model;
    this.color = color;
    this.year = year;
    this.price = price;
    this.carries = carries;
  }
}
```

The `abstract` modifier for the class prevents you from create a new instance of a `Car`. So why would define a constructor for a class you can't create an instance of? This is so you can call it in the constructor of any subclasses.

Here is an example of how you could model the `Sedan` class:

```
public class Sedan extends Car {
  public boolean fourWD;
  public boolean isHeavyDuty;

  public Sedan(String make, String model, String color, int year, double price, String carries, boolean fourWD, boolean isHeavyDuty) {
    super(make, model, color, year, price, carries);
    this.fourWD = fourWD;
    this.isHeavyDuty = isHeavyDuty;
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    String name = "Sedan";
    String main = (color + " " + make + " " + model + " " + name + " (" + year + ") costs $" + price);
    return main;
  }
}
```

The `extends Car` lets you build on top of the logic defined in the `Car` class. Here, the `Sedan` constructor can call the `Car` constructor by using `super` and passing the necessary arguments. You can then override the `toString` method like you have before.

You can create similar classes for SUV, Truck, and Van so you don't need to repeat common fields, and can focus on what differentiates each type of vehicle.

So how does all of this help you with your initial problem of searching for a String? In your `AutoPark` class you can have a `List<Car>` to keep track of all the cars in the park. Since each of these objects will be of type `Car`, you will be able to make certain assumptions about all of them, for example each will have a `make` field. You can also add any instances of the `Car` class to this `List`, instead of having to create a new variable.

Now when you search for a String in `searchItems`, you can loop through all of the cars to see if any of the fields contains the String you're searching for. If you're using a for-each loop it might look something like this:

```
for (Car car: cars) {
  if (car.make.contains(initItem) || car.model.contains(initItem)) {
    System.out.println("TRUE");
    break;
  } else {
    System.out.println("False!");
  }
}
```